# How to create a private mixin in sass

Tags: sass

So according to sass doc at https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use

$-radius is a private variable:

```
$-radius: 3px;

@mixin rounded {
  border-radius: $-radius;
}
```

if I change the mixin from rounded to -rounded, would the mixin be private too?

Answer (score 2):

Yes if you create a `_rounded()` or `-rounded()` mixin it will be private to the current file :

```
// border.scss
@mixin _rounded() {
    color: red;
    border-radius: 4px;
}


// foo.scss
@use "border";

.foo {
    @include _rounded() // This will throw an error
}
```